Нужна ли запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым?
Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

Яна после расторжения помолвки до всего этого замеса делает глупость.


Не нужна.
Яна делает глупость, и не важно, после чего и до чего.
Но если очень хочется знаков, прям невтерпёж, - можно!
Яна - после расторжения помолвки до всего этого замеса - делает глупость.
Яна, после расторжения помолвки до всего этого замеса, делает глупость.

В качестве варианта:
Яна, после расторжения помолвки и до всего этого замеса, делает глупость.
Пояснение

Без обособления распространенный обстоятельственный оборот в структуре данного простого предложении сложно прочесть.

Для улучшения стилистики два обстоятельства желательно соединить союзом И.


